# CSS add a right margin to element that is wider than screen

Tags: css, margins

I have a set of forms on my webpage, they are dynamically generated and the width ends up being wider than the screen (this isn't a problem as it is designed to replace an exel spreadsheet with the same issue).

```
<body>
    <div class='indented-form'>
        <table>
          ... table elements here
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

css

```
body {
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.indented-form {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

I have "margin:10px" on the div  that contains the table. 
This adds a margin at the left of the page as I expect, but scrolling right, the table reaches the edge without any margin. (The div seems to be taking its width from the body, which in turn seems to be based on browser width.)

How do I make it include a margin at the right, even though the table is wider than the browser?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make your `div` an `inline-block` element, it will stretch to fit the `table` inside it:

```
.indented-form {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyzoem6v/1)